# tf.boolean_mask, mask_dimension must be specified?

Tags: filter, tensorflow, boolean, tensor

When using `tf.boolean_mask()`, a Value Error is raised. It reads "Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None. E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.

I suspect that something is going wrong when I create my boolean mask s, because when I just create a boolean mask by hand, all works fine. However, I've checked the shape and the dtype of s so far, and couldn't notice anything suspicious. Both seemed to be identical to the shape and type of the boolean mask I created by hand.

[Please see a screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZfPa.png)
The following should allow you to reproduce the error on your machine. You need tensorflow, numpy and scipy.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # receive five embedded vectors
    v0 = tf.constant([[3.0,1.0,2.,4.,2.]])
    v1 = tf.constant([[4.0,0,1.0,4,1.]])
    v2 = tf.constant([[1.0,1.0,0.0,4.,8.]])
    v3 = tf.constant([[1.,4,2.,5.,2.]])
    v4 = tf.constant([[3.,2.,3.,2.,5.]])

    # concatenate the five embedded vectors into a matrix
    VT = tf.concat([v0,v1,v2,v3,v4],axis=0)

    # perform SVD on the concatenated matrix
    s, u1, u2   = tf.svd(VT)
    e = tf.square(s) # list of eigenvalues
    v = u1 # eigenvectors as column vectors

    # sample a set
    s = tf.py_func(sample_dpp_bin,[e,v],tf.bool)
    X = tf.boolean_mask(VT,s)
    print(X.eval())
```

This is the code to generate s. s is a sample from a determinantal point process (for the mathematically interested).
Note that I'm using tf.py_func to wrap this python function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import orth

def sample_dpp_bin(e_val,e_vec):
    # e_val = np.array of eigenvalues
    # e_vec = array of eigenvectors (= column vectors)
    eps = 0.01

    # sample a set of eigenvectors
    ind = (np.random.rand(len(e_val)) <= (e_val)/(1+e_val))
    k = sum(ind)
    if k == e_val.size:
        return np.ones(e_val.size,dtype=bool) # check for full set
    if k == 0:
        return np.zeros(e_val.size,dtype=bool)
    V = e_vec[:,np.array(ind)]

    # sample a set of k items 
    sample = np.zeros(e_val.size,dtype=bool)
    for l in range(k-1,-1,-1):
        p = np.sum(V**2,axis=1)
        p = np.cumsum(p / np.sum(p)) # item cumulative probabilities
        i = int((np.random.rand() <= p).argmax()) # choose random item
        sample[i] = True

        j = (np.abs(V[i,:])>eps).argmax() # pick an eigenvector not orthogonal to e_i
        Vj = V[:,j]
        V = orth(V - (np.outer(Vj,(V[i,:]/Vj[i]))))

    return sample
```

The output if I print s and `tf.reshape(s)` is

```
[False  True  True  True  True]
[5]
```

The output if I print VT and `tf.reshape(VT)` is

```
[[ 3.  1.  2.  4.  2.]
 [ 4.  0.  1.  4.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  4.  8.]
 [ 1.  4.  2.  5.  2.]
 [ 3.  2.  3.  2.  5.]]
[5 5]
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what is VT in your code ??

Comment: Just a tensor of shape [5 5], s and t are both the same dimension [5]

Comment: could you print shape of VT and s before boolean mask ?

Comment: yes, I can print both VT and s, and their respective shapes. I can attach another picture of it if it helps? The only trouble comes when I try to use the tf.boolean_mask command with VT and s, I've just tried it with a matrix of constants directly instead of VT and the same error was raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following example works for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tensor = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
mask = np.array([True, False, True])

t_m = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(t_m))
```

Output:

```
[[1 2]
 [5 6]]
```

Provide your runnable code snippet to reproduce the error. I think you might be doing something wrong in s.

## Update:

```
s = tf.py_func(sample_dpp_bin,[e,v],tf.bool)
s_v = (s.eval())
X = tf.boolean_mask(VT,s_v)
print(X.eval())
```

mask should be a np array not TF tensor. You don't have to use tf.pyfunc.

Comment: yeah, I'll add the code of s, because I think the thing is going wrong there. If I define a mask directly in numpy and use it, it works for me too.  Give me a minute to copy the code for s.

Comment: How does VT estimated ? could you just print shapes of VT and s and paste it above please ?

Comment: I appreciate, that you added your code. Could you print "s" and shape of s ? Sorry for asking more and more. I can't reproduce it as you did not provide e_val and e_vec ?

Comment: sorry, let me provide you with e_val and e_vec too. For the sake of completeness, I'll rework the entire post above.

Comment: just added the missing bit, hope it makes sense, otherwise just let me know if I should something else. I'll probably try to clean my entire post up tomorrow; it got a bit messy now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Update works for me too. Are you able to shed some light on why it works? Maybe tensorflow doesn't know the shape of s in advance, because it comes from a custom python function and that's solved by using only something that gets evaluated explicitly beforehand?

Comment: I think, it needs np array not tensor. It was not able to operate on tensor.

Comment: @HarshaPokkalla That's not correct.  The docs state that mask must be a "boolean tensor" (which also allows np.arrays).  The problem is the undefined shape.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the shape of the mask is not defined.  What do you get if you print `tf.shape(s)`?  I'd bet the problem with your code is that the shape of `s` is completely unknown, and you could fix that with a simple call like `s.set_shape((None))` (to simply specify that `s` is a 1-dimensional tensor).  Consider this code snippet:

```
X = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 100, 3))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    X_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.int8)
    # X_tf.set_shape((None, None, None))
    y = tf.greater(tf.reduce_max(X_tf, axis=(0, 1)), 0)
    print(tf.shape(y))
    z = tf.boolean_mask(X_tf, y, axis=2)
    print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={X_tf: X}))
```

This prints a shape of `Tensor("Shape_3:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)` (i.e., even the dimensions of `y` are unknown) and returns the same error as you have.  However, if you uncomment the `set_shape` line, then `X_tf` is known to be 3-dimensional and so `s` is 1-dimensional.  The code then works.  So, I think all you need to do is add a `s.set_shape((None))` call after the `py_func` call.